# Display the message if the size = 0 - visual force page

Tags: apex, visualforce

Is there a way to display a message if the list has 0 records? in VisualForce Page? so my idea is to display something like this in the `Pageblock`

```
 <apex:pageBlock title="Contacts">
      There are no records to display {!SelectedContacts.size=0}.
   </apex:pageBlock>
```

here is my visual force page actually I have:

```
<apex:pageblock id="Selected_PBS" title="Selected Contact"  >
  <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!SelectedContacts}" var="contact">
     <apex:column value="{!contact.Name}"/>
     <apex:column value="{!contact.Email}"/>
     <apex:column value="{!contact.Phone}"/>
  </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using two pageBlocks you can conditionally render the `title` value in `apex:pageBlock` to show the availability and unavailability of Objects in list. I have modified only the `title` attribute in your code.

```
<apex:pageblock id="Selected_PBS" title="{!IF(SelectedContacts != NULL && SelectedContacts.size > 0,'Selected Contact','There are no records to display')}">
  <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!SelectedContacts}" var="contact">
    <apex:column value="{!contact.Name}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!contact.Email}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!contact.Phone}"/>
  </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The value 'null' is not valid for operator '>'
Error is in expression '{!IF(SelectedContacts.size > 0,'Selected Contact','There are no records to display')}' in component <apex:pageBlock>

Comment: My Bad. I assumed SelectedContacts will not be null and just checked its size. Now added a null check as well and updated my answer.

Comment: 1+ is there a way to avoid render the `pageblocktable`? if the `SelectedContact` size = 0?

Comment: use rendered="{!IF(SelectedContacts != NULL && SelectedContacts.size > 0,true,false)}" in pageblocktable

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `<apex:outputText>` and if the list size is 0 render it.

```
<apex:pageblock id="Selected_PBS" title="Selected Contact"  >
 <apex:outputText value="There are no records to display" rendered="{!SelectedContacts.size==0}" />
  <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!SelectedContacts}" var="contact">
     <apex:column value="{!contact.Name}"/>
     <apex:column value="{!contact.Email}"/>
     <apex:column value="{!contact.Phone}"/>
  </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

You can check about `<apex:outputText>` in  [salesforce Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputText.htm).

Comment: `<apex:outputText` requires to have `<apex:page>` but my question is how can I incorporate the change in my existing code?

Comment: <apex:outputText> simplest answer @vikas Can you please add a curly bracket in the starting of rendered attribute and / in the end of tag. Just to make it perfect! :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use rendered:

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Contacts" rendered="{!SelectedContacts.size == 0}">
    There are no records to display
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Or:

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Contacts">
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!SelectedContacts.size == 0}">
    There are no records to display
    </apex:outputPanel>
    This text will always show.
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: did not show the message and i have tried both